# error in grammar about willSet and didSet,

Tags: swift

I'm studying grammar about willSet and didSet, but I got error

```
Playground execution failed:error: 21. プロパティの値を監視しよう.playground:15:15: 
error: argument passed to call that takes no argumentsvar 
   JAM = AAA("EEE", 5)
         ~^~~~~~~~~
```

what I coded is below

```
class AAA {
var name : String = "eee"
var number : Int = 4 {
willSet{
    print("\(number) -> \(newValue)")   // <- 値の変更前　ここで、出力していることはただ値がこれから変わるよ！ということだけである。
}
didSet{
    print("Changed: \(number - oldValue)" ) // <- 値の変更後　ここで、出力していることはただ値がこれから変わったよ！ということだけである。だから、Changed: に何かコード的な意味があるわけではない。
}
}
}
var JAM = AAA("EEE", 5)
```

please help me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
var JAM = AAA("EEE", 5)
```

looks for an initializer in the class AAA, which you did not provide. It is not implicitly defined.

In order for that line to work you need to provide an initializer function inside the class like so:

```
init(_ name: String, _ number: Int) {
    self.name = name
    self.number = number
}
```

The underscore allows you to leave out the argument labels in the call to the initializer.

Comment: thank you for your answer.
I declared the code below instead of initializer.
please let me know why it is not ok if I only declared the code below
var name : String = "eee"
var number : Int = 4

Comment: The code you are using always initializes those variables to the values you provided. If you want to set other value from outside upon construction using the syntax AAA("EEE", 5) you MUST provide an initializer. Otherwise you would have to set the variables one by one: JAM.name = "AAA" and JAM.number = 5